# Embedded Tomcat forwarding to JSP not working

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am using embedded tomcat, with following configuration

```
    String webappDirLocation = "webapp/";
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    System.out.println(new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
    tomcat.setBaseDir(".");
    tomcat.setPort(4041);
    Context ctx = tomcat.addWebapp(tomcat.getHost(), "", new    
     File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
    ((StandardJarScanner) ctx.getJarScanner()).setScanAllDirectories(true);

    tomcat.start();

    tomcat.getServer().await();'
```

but when i am forwarding to JSP using

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

it says not JSP found to the path

web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>accManager.Hello</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- The mappings for the JSP servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Can anyone help me to find what is wrong i am doing here ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

WEB-INF directory is private. Client cannot access WEB-INF via a URL request. WEB-INF normally holds the web.xml, classes, and lib directories, but you can put anything you want to hide from the client there. Some framework like spring allow serving pages from WEB-INF using special resource configurations[ mvc:resources in case of spring.].

Try placing you jsp page in your web container out side of WEB-INF and META-INF folder.
eg:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

Comment: i am also using the same, but here is the issue with the embedded tomcat as it don't have default web.xml, request dispatcher is also not working

Answer (score 1):

You can't access to WEB-INF contents directly from an URL Request. Try to remove it, and since you'r mapping the servlet with any file with the extension .jsp, you can use one of thus paths :

```
views/jsp/index.jsp
jsp/index.jsp
index.jsp
```